# how about node.js change its api?

Tags: node.js

I'm using node.js to make a http request to a host. I found the latest version of node.js of 0.6.7 that make a request is like this

```
var http = require('http');
var req = http.request(options, function(res) { 
        var result ='';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) { 
            //console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
            result += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', function () { 
            console.log('end:' + result);
      });
});
```

But I also found that the 0.3 version of node.js that make a request like this

```
  http.createClient(80, 'api.t.sina.com.cn')
      .request('GET', '/statuses/public_timeline.json?source=3243248798', {'host': 'api.t.sina.com.cn'})
      .addListener('response', function(response){
         var result = ''
         response.addListener('data',function(data){
            result += data
         })
         .addListener('end',function(){
            tweets = JSON.parse(result)
         })
      })
```

But the 0.3 version of 'createClient' api is deprecated in 0.6.7. And I don't find any docs that describe this.
I'm worrying about the api will change in the future. That will make my code not run in the future.
Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API **has and will** change. That's the caveat for using bleeding-edge tech, like Node. The only advice I can give is to update your code to use the latest API, after all it's not changing *that* often, or just stick to a working version if you don't have the resources to keep upgrading your code base.. I personally keep my Node projects pretty small, that way upgrading is easier.

Also the use of NPM modules and generally modular code is encouraged. That way some API changes are easy update. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't found api changelog in nodejs.org.

Comment: I don't know of any changelog for api changes, but you can always see http://nodejs.org/changelog.html and http://blog.nodejs.org/ and https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ChangeLog for changes.

Comment: You can get changelog like so: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.6.7/ChangeLog

Answer (score 2):

Node 0.3 is astonishingly ancient, and Node moves remarkably fast.

The Node API will change, you need to constantly keep your platform up to date. While this can be annoying, it's also one of the best parts of Node. It keeps people in the habit of upgrading, allowing the Node platform and ecosystem to continually improve without the stifling hassles of backwards compatibility.

If you want a less frequently changing API, perhaps PHP or Java is more suitable for you. There's also nothing stopping you from continuing to use the older versions of Node. :D